# Wordpress redirect to page based on questionnaire answers

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, redirect, woocommerce

I am trying to create a questionnaire on my woocommerce page which will redirect users to a given page (3 options) based on the answers they input. There is documentation on how to do this for product filters, but I believe mine should be a simpler implementation.

**Scenario**

1. The shopper selects a ‘Recommend a Product’ option.
2. The shopper is asked a series of questions.
3. Based on the answers provided, a product page is recommended
   to the shopper (Small, Medium or Large).

I've read the below article which describes how to implement it based on a product filter using Gravity Forms but this is a more complex scenario than I require...I simply need to set a page re-direct based on the answers given.

[How to Create a Questionnaire based WooCommerce Product Filter](https://wisdmlabs.com/blog/how-to-create-a-questionnaire-based-woocommerce-product-filter/)

Any help appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: what have you tried before asking SO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. Possible using the WPForms plugin with the following code:

```
function wpf_custom_redirect( $url, $form_id, $fields ) {

    // Only consider changing the redirect if its for form #50
    if ( '50' == $form_id ) {
        // In the example below, we look at the submitted value for field #5
        // If that value is "test", then we change the redirect URL
        if ( !empty( $field['5']['value'] ) && 'test' == $field['5']['value'] ) {
            $url = 'https://wpforms.com';
        }
    }
    return $url;
}
add_filter( 'wpforms_process_redirect_url', 'wpf_custom_redirect', 10, 3 );
```